# PhantomJS Memory Exhausted error when using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I've searched all over the web for a solution with no luck so far. I know this is a documented issue, but I am only trying to load a single web page and all the responses have been "this happens trying to do tests on 200 pages".

I have tried:

`page.settings.loadImages = true;
 page.settings.loadplugins = false;`

I added the ``page.close()` even though like I said, it's only with one URL right now.

I've tried setting `loadImages` to false as well. It works fine when I remove my one line of JavaScript (for example replacing it with `document.title` but as soon as that line is there, the memory usage rockets to 1000MB and then it quits.

My only goal is to check if a certain element exists on the page. How can I resolve this issue? None of the solutions I've found online are working for me.

The code in question:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Chrome/52.0.2743.116';
var url = 'http://www.example.com/';
var ending = system.args[1];
ending = encodeURIComponent(ending);
url = url + ending;

page.settings.loadImages = false;
page.settings.loadplugins = false;

page.viewportSize = { width: 1680, height: 1050 };

page.open(url, function(status) {
setTimeout(function(){
  var elem = page.evaluate(function() {
    return $(".primary-info")[0];
  });
  if(!elem){
    console.log('no image found');
    page.render(ending+'.png');
      }
    page.close();
    phantom.exit();
      }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just return the whole object, there could be quite a lot of its attributes. Only take what is necessary:

```
  var elem = page.evaluate(function() {
    var data = {};
    var item = $(".primary-info")[0];
    data.title = item.value;
    data.color = item.style.color;
    return data;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I think it works now! Oh you saved me so much manual work... I had no idea that it was trying to return so much